# When can we use an identifier number instead of its name in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, identifier

I am developing a software need to remove user provided numbers but unfortunately some elements like column names (unrelated to user input) also can be represent by numbers. So I am looking for a complete reference to know when a column name or (maybe table name) can represented in a query by an id.

For example in the query below this situation is established:

```
 select * from first group by 1,2,3;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Positional references to *output* columns are valid in the [**`GROUP BY`** and **`ORDER BY`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html) clauses of a `SELECT` statement.

> **`GROUP BY` Clause**
>   *expression* can be an input column name, or the name **or ordinal number**
>   of an output column (SELECT list item)
>
> **`ORDER BY` Clause**
>   Each *expression* can be the name **or ordinal number** of an output column
>   (SELECT list item)

And also [**`DISTINCT ON`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

> The `DISTINCT ON` expressions are interpreted using the same rules as for `ORDER BY`.

Example:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Comment: thank you.can we say ONLY this two Command use this type of referencing?

Comment: @CoderInNetwork: You might be interested in the added `DISTINCT ON`.