# Selecting first and last row within a time interval

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have a table named `trades` for holding currency trading data with the following schema:

```
id        - uuid
timestamp - timestamp without time zone
price     - numeric
```

I would like to be able to query in a way that I can build a candle chart. For this I need the *first price*, the *last price*, the *max price* and the *min price*, grouped by time intervals. So far I have this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ts_round( timestamptz, INT4 ) RETURNS TIMESTAMPTZ AS $$
SELECT 'epoch'::timestamptz
     + '1 second'::INTERVAL * ( $2 * ( extract( epoch FROM $1 )::INT4 / $2 ) );
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT ts_round( timestamp, 300 ) AS interval_timestamp
     , max(price) AS max, min(price) AS min
FROM trades
GROUP BY interval_timestamp
ORDER BY interval_timestamp DESC
```

How do I get the *first price* and *last price* within these intervals?

Comment: How are you defining `first price` and `last price`? By timestamp?

Comment: I seriously doubt that your function does what you actually want. It's effectively *truncating* to *n*-second intervals, after *rounding* to full seconds. I suspect your really want to either truncate ***or*** round to *n*-second intervals. Right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Given time/interval to calculate open/high/low/close value in each grouped data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27399054/given-time-interval-to-calculate-open-high-low-close-value-in-each-grouped-data)

Comment: Erwin, thanks for the feedback! Could you suggest how the function could be improved? Or should I create a new question for that?

Comment: @MattBeedle: What should it do exactly?

Comment: I just need a way to group the trades into arbitrary time intervals to calculate min/max/first/last etc during that timeframe. I took the function from http://www.depesz.com/2010/10/22/grouping-data-into-time-ranges/. Perhaps I can get rid of the function completely?

Comment: The question that you linked to in your answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27399054/given-time-interval-to-calculate-open-high-low-close-value-in-each-grouped-data/27399571#27399571) is exactly what I am trying to do, except with a the interval time being variable.

Comment: A much easier way to get the timestamp interval is using the floor function with a unix timestamp.
 This would return in n intervals (n is in minutes)
floor(unix_timestamp/(n*60))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is the query you want:

```
SELECT ts_round( timestamp, 300 ) AS interval_timestamp,
       max(firstprice) as firstprice,
       max(lastprice) as lastprice,
       max(price) AS maxprice, min(price) AS minprice
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             first_value(price) over (partition by ts_round(timestamp, 300) order by timestamp) as firstprice,
             first_value(price) over (partition by ts_round(timestamp, 300) order by timestamp desc) as lastprice
      FROM trades t
     ) t
GROUP BY interval_timestamp
ORDER BY interval_timestamp DESC;
```

Comment: One can have a window function over the result of an aggregate function on the same query level, but not the other way round. While `min()` and `max()` can be used for either purpose, `first_value()` and `last_value()` are dedicated window functions. This is syntactical **nonsense**, you would need a subquery to make it work. Doesn't seem to keep people from voting for it, though.

Comment: **Still incorrect** after your fix. The default frame definition for window frames is `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`. In your subquery you effectively get the price of the *current* row as `lastprice`. After `max(lastprice)` in the outer query you effectively return `max(price)` a second time, which is nonsense. Still doesn't keep people from voting for it.

Comment: Instead of calling two times first_value, you can call first_value and last_value on same window function. Query will be faster.

Answer (score 2):

This uses a *single* window for all window functions and no subquery. Should be faster than the currently accepted answer.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (1)
       ts_round(timestamp, 300) AS interval_timestamp
     , min(price)         OVER w AS min_price
     , max(price)         OVER w AS max_price
     , first_value(price) OVER w AS first_price
     , last_value(price)  OVER w AS last_price
FROM   trades
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY ts_round(timestamp, 300) ORDER BY timestamp
             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
ORDER  BY 1 DESC;
```

To define "first" and "last" per `timestamp`, this column needs to be unique or the query is ambiguous and yo get an arbitrary pick from equal peers.

Similar answer with explanation for the custom window frame:

- [Given time/interval to calculate open/high/low/close value in each grouped data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27399054/given-time-interval-to-calculate-open-high-low-close-value-in-each-grouped-data/27399571#27399571)

Explanation for the reference by ordinal numbers:

- [When can we use an identifier number instead of its name in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24596290/when-can-we-use-an-identifier-number-instead-of-its-name-in-postgresql/24596349#24596349)

Aside: don't use "timestamp" as identifier. It's a basic type name, which is error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done without creating a confusing function and just using the built-in floor function with a unix timestamp.

```
SELECT symbol, timestamp AS interval_timestamp,
   max(firstprice) as firstprice,
   max(lastprice) as lastprice,
   max(price) AS maxprice, min(price) AS minprice, 
   max(vol)-min(vol) as volume
FROM (SELECT t.*,
first_value(price) over (partition by 
floor(unix_timestamp(timestamp)/(5*60)) order by timestamp) as 
firstprice,
first_value(price) over (partition by 
floor(unix_timestamp(timestamp)/(5*60)) order by timestamp desc) as 
lastprice
  FROM trades t
 ) t
GROUP BY floor(unix_timestamp(timestamp)/(5*60))
ORDER BY timestamp
```

Note here you are turning the timestamp into a unix timestamp (if you are storing unix timestmaps no need to convert) and then dividing that by number of minutes * 60. So, in this example we are returning 5 minutes intervals. I also added in the trade volume for the time interval because, why not?