# ORDER BY changed column with same name

Tags: sql, postgresql, replace, pattern-matching, sql-order-by

I have a table `artist` with several columns like `name`, `type` ...
I want the column `name` to be returned and ordered alphabetically, but the column name should be adjusted. If the name of the artist starts with *'the '* (case insensitive) then it should be removed and placed behind the name in uppercase, for example *'the Beatles'* -> *'Beatles, THE'*.

This is the code I have (it doesn't work):

```
SELECT name,
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(name) LIKE 'THE %' THEN CONCAT(RIGHT(name, length(name)-4),', THE')
  END AS name 
FROM artist
ORDER BY name
```

Problem 1: `name` is not replaced, it creates a new column.

Problem 2: new column has same name => column `name` is ambiguous in `order by name`.

How can I easily solve those problems?

Comment: *Always* add your version of Postgres, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ELSE` clause in `CASE`:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(name) LIKE 'THE %' THEN CONCAT(RIGHT(name, length(name)-4),', THE')
    ELSE name
  END AS name 
FROM artist
ORDER BY name
```

Comment: This doesn't address: `Problem 2: new column has same name => column name is ambiguous in order by name.`

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter `Problem 1. name is not replaced, it creates a new column.`. Original name is replaced by `CASE` and alias. I don't see why this is ambiguous http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2a6d2/1/0. Could you provide sqlfiddle with error?

Comment: `ORDER BY name` raises an exception if there are multiple columns named name in the output.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter The point is in my query there is no multiple columns. Author states clearly that he wants to replace name, not create new column, if he wants 2 columns then aliases are needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want this for ordering, then you can put the logic only in the `order by` clause:

```
order by (case when name ilike 'the%'
               then substring(name from 5) || ', The'
               else name
          end)
```

If you also want this column in the `select` clause, then use an alias other than `name`.  That is already used for your first column:

```
select name,
       (case when name ilike 'the%'
             then substring(name from 5) || ', The'
             else name
        end) as munged_name
. . .
order by munged_name
```

Note:  `ilike` is a Postgres extension for case-insensitive `like`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Query

```
SELECT CASE WHEN name ILIKE 'THE %'  -- simpler
            THEN right(name, -4) || ', THE'  -- simpler, faster
            ELSE name END AS name  -- but better use a distinct alias
      , *
FROM   artist
ORDER  BY 1;  -- positional reference to 1st output column
```

#### Rationale

- The simplest and fastest expression to get a string *minus* n leading characters is: [`right(string, -n)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER).
- `ILIKE` is simpler than `lower()` / `upper() LIKE ...`.
- You don't need [`concat()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER), the plain concatenation operator [`||`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) does the same faster since the expression `right(name, -4)` is *guaranteed* to be `NOT NULL` in this context.
- When confused with SQL visibility rules for column names, or when there are **duplicate output column names** (which is totally legit in Postgres) you can also use **positional references** in `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY` or `DISTINCT ON (...)` clauses:

  - [When can we use an identifier number instead of its name in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24596290/when-can-we-use-an-identifier-number-instead-of-its-name-in-postgresql/24596349#24596349)
  - [How to re-use result for SELECT, WHERE and ORDER BY clauses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074546/how-to-re-use-result-for-select-where-and-order-by-clauses/14075977#14075977)

  However, it's hardly wise or useful to *have* duplicate output column names in the first place. Rather use distinct names.
- If you run this query a lot I suggest a [functional index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-expressional.html) on the same expression for much faster results:

  ```
  CREATE INDEX artist_name_sort_idx ON artist 
   ((CASE WHEN name ILIKE 'THE %' THEN right(name, -4) || ', THE' ELSE name END));
  ```

The expression in the query must be the same to employ this index.

#### Proper test case

```
WITH artist(artist_id, name) AS (
   VALUES
      (1, 'The Beatles')   
    , (2, 'tHe bEatles')
    , (3, 'The The')
    , (4, 'Then')
    , (5, 'The X')
    , (6, 'Theodor')
    , (7, 'Abba')
    , (8, 'ZZ TOP')
    , (9, 'The ')  -- unlikely corner case, I don't think it would pay to test for it
    , (10, '')      -- empty string
    , (11, NULL)   -- NULL
   )
SELECT CASE WHEN name ILIKE 'THE %' THEN right(name, -4) || ', THE' ELSE name END AS name
      , *
FROM   artist
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Result:

```
     name     | artist_id |    name
--------------+-----------+-------------
              |        10 |
 , THE        |         9 | The           -- remaining corner case
 Abba         |         7 | Abba
 bEatles, THE |         2 | tHe bEatles
 Beatles, THE |         1 | The Beatles
 The, THE     |         3 | The The
 Then         |         4 | Then
 Theodor      |         6 | Theodor
 X, THE       |         5 | The X
 ZZ TOP       |         8 | ZZ TOP
 <NULL>       |        11 | <NULL>
```